# Java and Json- Securing json input strings from injections

Tags: java, json, security, escaping

I am using fasterxml and wonder how I have to handle the incoming string to prevent any kind of injections :( I googled a lot now and can't find the right informations. Can anyone help me out with this?

Updated: What I was trying to ask is that I was asked to escape the incoming json strings so that the requests can't be abused. But I can't find useful informations about Json escaping as it seems to allow quite a lot of signs.

Comment: By "fasterxml", do you actually mean [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)? What kind of injections do you have in mind?

Comment: Yes Jackson. Thats the problem, I dont even know how to inject. I have a velocity template which I have to fill with parameters that I get from json. Then this template will be sent to Elasticsearch. I dont want users to inject stuff they should not be allowed to.

Comment: Added informations about my goal to escape json

Comment: You explained what an injection is, but not what you are afraid of. JSON has a very limited grammar and most decent JSON parsers should be able to handle it correctly.

Comment: I am sending parsed values (extracted from json) to Elasticsearch. But I am losing escaping. And I have to secure the Elasticsearch request from exploits. So I have to apply the json escaping again. I am confused myself :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String escaped = gson.toJson(value);
        if(value instanceof String) {

            if(escaped.startsWith("\"")) {
                escaped = escaped.substring(1);
            }
            if(escaped.endsWith("\"")) {
                escaped = escaped.substring(0, escaped.length() - 1);
            }
            return escaped;
        }
        value = escaped;
```